# embed animation plots generated by in a Markdown or html file outside Rmd and shiny

Tags: r, animation, plotly, htmlwidgets, ggiraph

I have searched several R animation packages, such as,

- `htmlwidget`
- `ggiraph`
- `plotly`

All packages can be used for `Rmd` and `shiny`.

But I want to put the animated graphs on my hexo blog or other websites created from scratch by myself. (Hexo is a statistic website generator, similar to `Jekyll` and `Hugo`)

- blog part

  Yihui Xie created a package `blogdown`. Animation plots do not work even on the sample hexo site created by him with `blogdown`.
- website part

  There are lots of JavaScript animation libraries. The usual usage of the libraries is to include 1) a reference link to JavaScript library and 2) JavaScript code blocks containing data.

  All R packages found online do not supply any of them.

For R animation packages, how can I find 1) all reference links to JavaScript libraries used by the package and 2) JavaScript code blocks containing data for each animation plot generated by the package? These codes will be embedded in a Markdown or html file.

Thank you.